# Can't get google test to work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, googletest

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(BattleUnitTest, CountryReturnsProperName) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I can't seem to get google test to work. I ran Nuget package manager to get gtest. It keeps giving me these errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)" (?IsTrue@internal@testing@@YA_N_N@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall testing::internal::scoped_ptr<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >::reset(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > *)" (?reset@?$scoped_ptr@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@internal@testing@@QAEXPAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) Assignment1_Battle  E:\C++\Projects\Assignment1_Battle\Assignment1_Battle\BattleUnitTest.obj    1
```

.

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall testing::Message::Message(void)" (??0Message@testing@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall BattleUnitTest_CountryReturnsProperName_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@BattleUnitTest_CountryReturnsProperName_Test@@EAEXXZ)    Assignment1_Battle  E:\C++\Projects\Assignment1_Battle\Assignment1_Battle\BattleUnitTest.obj    1
```

.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::internal::EqFailure(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,bool)" (?EqFailure@internal@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@2@PBD0ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@1_N@Z) referenced in function "class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::internal::CmpHelperEQ<int,int>(char const *,char const *,int const &,int const &)" (??$CmpHelperEQ@HH@internal@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@1@PBD0ABH1@Z) Assignment1_Battle  E:\C++\Projects\Assignment1_Battle\Assignment1_Battle\BattleUnitTest.obj    1
```

I could post all the errors but almost all of them have to do with LNK2019. Does anyone know how to fix these errors?

Comment: As I remember you have to add two *.lib files in input field of linking section.

Comment: You are getting linker errors, so you probably need to include the `gtest` library in your project. It seems that you only included the path for the compiler to find header files.

Comment: It will become clearer if you posted how `link.exe` is called in your build process. Either paste the `<Link>` section from you .vcxproj file or the command line of how VS calls `link.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need some additional configuration of your test project:

1. Add gtest library name to you project properties (Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input). Be aware that you probably need to add this thing for both Debug and Release configurations and that library names are different (they are gtest.lib for Release and gtestd.lib for Debug; the difference is "d" at the end of the name before dot).
2. Add the path to the `gtest` library to your project properties (Project Properties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories). This also needs to be done separately for Debug and Release configurations, because the directories are different as well.

If something else goes wrong, this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/696481/Quick-start-unit-test-How-to-start-working-with-th) might be really useful. It contains the full scenario of setting up gtest for a project in Visual Studio without using Nuget. Just be aware that Nuget basically sets up already compiled version of gtest to "package" sub-directory of your project/solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but there was nothing wrong with my linker settings. I eventually tracked it down to this post [PrintTo link issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlemock/6OMfUJ5No4c):

> This was indeed caused by the mismatching /Zc:wchar_t setting. I
>   failed to mention in the previous post that I had made that example
>   code as Qt Console Application project (with Qt Add-in 1.1.9).
>   Apparently the wchar_t setting is set to 'no' with that project
>   template, while Google Mock's project setting is set to 'yes' by
>   default. When I recompiled Google Mock with the setting set to 'no'
>   the linker problem went away.

When I changed my setting "Treat WChar_t As Built in Type" to "Yes /Zc:wchar_t" the build worked.